# How to add scale/axisLabel to radar?

Tags: echarts

I'm developing a radar chart using echarts v4 and I want to add a scale to it.

I already tried to add:
`axisLabel: { show: true }`
but it doesn't work.

So my question is: is there any solution for this issue.
Here is an example so you can check it for more details: https://jsfiddle.net/skhachoum/k9x5rvn7/15/

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah.. It's a bug of echart 4.0, and this is a [bugfix](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/pull/10036), bug seems haven't release in last version.